# Xcode7 error when submitting app with bitcode enabled

Tags: objective-c, xcode7, bitcode

This question was asked before, but none of the answers provide a **real** solution or an explanation (just workarounds).

I am developing a framework (objecting-c) which complied with bitcode enabled. I am using this framework in another App project, which also enable bitcode.

When I am trying to submit the App I am getting the error:
`The archive did not contain <DVTFilePath:...> as expected.`

If I uncheck either "include app symbols..." or "include bitcode." it works fine and I don't get the error.

However, I would like to have **both** on (include the symbols and bitcode).
Any idea?